# Table alias -- Unknown column in field list

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a sql query which is executing a LEFT JOIN on 2 tables in which some of the columns are ambiguous.  I can prefix the joined tables but when I try to prefix one of the columns from the table in the FROM clause, it tells me Unknown column.  I even tried giving that table an alias like so ...From points AS p and using "p" to prefix the tables but that didn't work either.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is my query:

```
SELECT point_title, point_url, address, city, state, zip_code, 
     phone, `points`.`lat`, `points`.`longi`, featured, 
     kmlno, image_url, category.title, category_id, 
     point_id, lat, longi, reviews.star_points, reviews.review_id,
     count(reviews.point_id) as totals 
FROM (SELECT *, 
             ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37.7717185') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
               * cos( radians( longi ) - radians('-122.4438929') ) 
               + sin( radians('37.7717185') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM points 
      HAVING distance < '25') as distResults 
LEFT JOIN category USING ( category_id ) 
LEFT JOIN reviews USING ( point_id ) 
    WHERE  (point_title LIKE '%Playgrounds%' OR category.title LIKE '%Playgrounds%') 
 GROUP BY point_id 
 ORDER BY totals DESC, distance
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

Here is the schema for the tables involved:

Points table: 
Field   Type    Null    Default     Comments
point_id    int(11)     No
point_title     varchar(255)    No
category_id     int(11)     No
description     text    No
point_url   varchar(255)    No
address     varchar(255)    No
city    varchar(255)    No
state   varchar(255)    No
zip_code    varchar(255)    No
phone   varchar(255)    No
filename    varchar(255)    No
lat     varchar(25)     No
longi   varchar(25)     No
user_id     int(2)  No      0
featured    int(1)  No      0
status  int(1)  No      1
kmlno   int(2)  No      0
lastupdate  varchar(255)    No
image_url   varchar(255)    No

Reviews table:
Field   Type    Null    Default     Comments
review_id   int(11)     No
review  int(1)  No      0
review_title    varchar(255)    No
review_desc     text    No
star_points     int(11)     No      0
user_id     int(11)     No      0
point_id    int(11)     No
lat     varchar(25)     No
longi   varchar(25)     No
lastupdate  varchar(255)    No
status  varchar(1)  No      r

Category Table:
Field   Type    Null    Default     Comments
category_id     int(11)     No
title   varchar(255)    No
description     text    No
filename    varchar(255)    No
image_name  varchar(255)    No
status  int(1)  No      0
lastupdate  varchar(255)    No

Comment: Which column is giving you the problem? Can you format your query so that it's possible to read it?

Comment: I figured it out.  Instead of prefacing the lat and longi columns with 'points' I needed to preface with 'distResults' since that is the table alias being used.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your schema it's difficult to know for sure what the problem is. But I do see one problem - move the HAVING distance < 25 from the inner select to the outer select. The "distance" name is not available to the inner select. I've also changed HAVING to WHERE, since there was no GROUP BY.

```
SELECT point_title, point_url, address, city, state, zip_code, 
     phone, `points`.`lat`, `points`.`longi`, featured, 
     kmlno, image_url, category.title, category_id, 
     point_id, lat, longi, reviews.star_points, reviews.review_id,
     count(reviews.point_id) as totals 
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, 
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37.7717185') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
           * cos( radians( longi ) - radians('-122.4438929') ) + 
             sin( radians('37.7717185') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
      FROM points) AS distResultsInner
      WHERE distance<25)) AS distResults
LEFT JOIN category USING ( category_id ) 
LEFT JOIN reviews USING ( point_id ) 
WHERE  (point_title LIKE '%Playgrounds%' 
    OR category.title LIKE '%Playgrounds%') 
GROUP BY point_id ORDER BY totals DESC, distance 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: Ok thanks but I get this error with the above query: 
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS distResults LEFT JOIN category USING ( category_id ) LEFT JOIN reviews U' at line 11